# Using stageros and a simulated camera

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure how long this has been in the "stack" but does the existence of pantilt.inc and the ModelCamera definition in stage.hh mean that there is now hope for subscribing to camera images in stage?

If so, should this be some sort of plugin ala gazebo, or a new addition to stageros.cpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43238/using-stageros-and-a-simulated-camera/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-10-12**:
I like your patch so much. It is useful for my research. Thanks.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-12**:
Happy it helped someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally submitted the [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4058).
Updated the patch a bit.. had some time to fix the inversion issue..

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
Looks like that ticket migrated to https://github.com/rtv/Stage/issues/34